# struts2 result relative path

Tags: struts2

I store all my jspx templates in `/WEB-INF/templates/<package>/`

I am tired of copy/paste like

`<result name="success">/WEB-INF/templates/foo/success.jspx</result>`

<result name="fail">/WEB-INF/templates/foo/foo.jspx</result>

All my templates are in WEB-INF/templates/

Could I set it in one place for the whole package?

I briefly looked into the code and found noting about it expect `UiBean#getTemplateDir` that I need to hack to achieve my goal.

I wonder if there is an *official*  (not hack!) way to solve my issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is one property which is set in struts.property file

```
struts.ui.templateDir
```

i have not used it myself but i guess this is something which tell Struts2 where to look for template
something like

```
struts.ui.templateDir=/WEB-INF/templates
```

you can try something like this

Comment: Unfortunately this __path should be used for JSP control tag templates by default__. It does not help me(